# Certificate management: which party should request certificates?

Tags: domain, certificate

My question is concerned with proper certificate management.

Different parties provide domain / server / application services to our organisation.

1. One party manages our DNS (and more).
2. Another party manages several applications (on their servers).

At my current organisation, most of the "technical" IT administration work is outsourced to party 1.

Due to the nature of my organisation, we need both Domain Validation (DV) and Organization Validation (OV) certificates.

Party 2 (running an application for us on a server where the certificate must be installed) tells us either:

A - For DV certificates: "We don't control your domain so we can't request a certificate". My response would be: for DV certificates you can also prove control using your server (HTTP / URL proof). You don't need control over our DNS (which is managed by the other party).

B - For OV certificates: "we can't provide the proof during the certificate request - only you, someone working for your own organisation can."

Now I don't think it's good practice for one party to request a certificate and then send that certificate (and private key) to the party controlling the server, even if you'd send it via "secure" channels. I think you'd also want the party controlling the server where the certficate must be placed, to also do the request.

So long story short: who *should and can* request these certificates in our case? (and be the legal owner, monitor them, renew them, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the party who has hands on the private key whom should request the certificate.

The certification was designed to accomodate this. Lets take a simpler scenario: You are operating a webserver. You want a certificate. You generate a public and a private key. The public key is packaged as and referred to as a Certificate Singing Request (CSR). You send that to your Certificate Authority. They sign the CSR, thereby making it a certificate and send that back to you.

Good security minimizes the number of people with access to secrets and the resending of those secrets.

Hence it is "Party 2" whom should be requesting the signed certificate. However at this point it gets a little more complicated. The certificate and key *BELONGS* to you, however IMHO if Party 2 have an explicit, delegated responsible for dealing with deploying the certificate then they are also responsible for the provisioning process.

Check your contracts.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's completely in line with my understanding. The party controlling the server where the certificate is installed should be the one generating the CSR and private key - which should stay here and not be sent to other parties.

What I'm not completely sure of though:

Comment: Party 2 (controlling the server) should take care of the DV certificates, using HTTP/ URL validation, right? Their argument "we can't because we don't control. the domain" doesn't hold imo. And: could / should party 2 (an external party) also take care of the OV certificates?